# PHP Contact Form with Validatation Script?

Tags: php, validation, contact-form

I'd like to add a PHP Contact Form with Validation to my website.
I can't seem to find an easy to set-up form.

I have a few other desired features I hope would be in some tpye of script out there!

First,
I found a script that processes the form without page refresh.
Plugin can be found here//
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Second,
Name validation, if the name is shorter than 3 characters than the error text says 
something similar to 
"name can not be shorter than 3 characters"

and

Third,
Check for a VALID E-mail.
So a fake E-mail is not accepted.

Is there any type of plug-in out there that have these features?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are ready to graduate to a Model/View/Controller environment. Give Kohana a look. http://kohanaframework.org.

Using Kohana, you can specify rules for validation like so:

```
$extra_validation = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
    ->rule('password', 'min_length', array(':value', 8))
    ->rule('password_confirm', 'not_empty')
    ->rule('home_city', 'not_empty');

// Create the user using form values
$user = ORM::factory('user')->values($this->request->post(), array(
    'password',
    'home_city',
))->create($extra_validation);
```

Comment: Is there any type of step by step installation guide? Cause I don't understand anything inside the folders -_-

Comment: Based on the fact that you were saying there should be an easier way to do validation is what made me recommend a framework. Kohana isn't the only framework out there (there are others like CakePHP, Zend, etc) but it is the one I am familiar with and work with a lot. I would recommend taking a tutorial for Kohana. One can be found at http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/04/kohana-tutorial-beginners/